# How to take a picture and save it in a custom folder for my app visible in the Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I´ve been struggling with this for a few days now and other answers posted in similar questions here on stackoverflow haven´t helped me.

What I want to do is set a custom ArrayAdapter to my ListView and inside this adapter I want to set an onClickListener to a button that appears in every item. Then I want the user to pick whether he wants to take a picture with the camera or choose a picture from the gallery. Then I want the picture to save in the app´s own folder inside Gallery. However, although the custom folder is created and visible in Gallery, the picture itself is stored in the Camera folder and I can see a broken file in the custom folder.

I´ve read photobasics on the devsite http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, but it did not help much. 
I implemented the onActivityResult inside my Fragment but the Uri path is different fro the one created in the adapter.

Here is the code:

- In ArrayAdapter:

  ```
  photoPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override public void onClick(View v)
      {

          // Camera.
          final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
          final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          final PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
          final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
          for (ResolveInfo res : listCam)
          {
              final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
              final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
              intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
              intent.setPackage(packageName);
              cameraIntents.add(intent);
          }

          // Filesystem.
          final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
          galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
          galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

          // Chooser of filesystem options.
          final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Vyber zdroj");

          // Add the camera options.
          chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

          if (chooserIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null)
          {
              // Create the File where the photo should go
              File photoFile = null;
              try
              {
                  photoFile = createImageFile();
              }
              catch (IOException ex)
              {
                  // Error occurred while creating the File

              }
              // Continue only if the File was successfully created
              if (photoFile != null)
              {
                  chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                         Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                  Log.i(TAG,"uri from file:"+Uri.fromFile(photoFile).toString());
                  chooserIntent.putExtra("path",mCurrentPhotoPath);
                  fragment.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FlowListUtils.getIdFromDate(experience.getDate()));
              }
          }
      }
  });


   private File createImageFile() throws IOException
  {

  // Create an image file name
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
  String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
  String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+"/MyApp";

  File storageDir = new File(storagePath);
  storageDir.mkdirs();

  File image = File.createTempFile(
          imageFileName,  /* prefix */
          ".jpg",         /* suffix */
          storageDir      /* directory */
  );

  // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
  mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
  Log.i(TAG,"mCurrent Photo Path in adapter:"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
  return image;
  }
  ```
- This code is in my Fragment

  ```
   @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  ExperienceAdapter.dateForPicture = requestCode;
  ExperienceAdapter.uriForPicture = data.getData();


  galleryAddPic(path);
  }


  private void galleryAddPic(String path)
  {
  Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  File f = new File(ExperienceAdapter.mCurrentPhotoPath);

  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
  mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
  getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
  }
  ```

The path I add to the intent is file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/JPEG_20140626_133228_1332202116.jpg
but suddenly changes to content://media/external/images/media/6273 in the Intent return by onActivityResult.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you store in internal or external storage ?

Comment: I want to store the pictures so that they are available to the user in a custom folder visible in the gallery folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function to save the Image,

```
public static String saveImageInExternalCacheDir(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String myfileName) {
    String fileName = myfileName.replace(' ', '_') + getCurrentDate().toString().replace(' ', '_').replace(":", "_");
    String filePath = (context.getExternalCacheDir()).toString() + "/" + fileName + ".jpg";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow policy on self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Did that make you feel better, SHIDHI?

Answer (score 0):

You have a really good example here -> [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

When you go save with `createImageFile` function you can choose your directory url:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);]
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,
    ".jpg",
    storageDir
);
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
return image;
}
```

I think this is what you need!

Comment: This is exactly what I am using, if you take a look. It doesn´t create the custom folder though.